# Using SWT with "lein repl" on Mac OS X

Tags: clojure, swt, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

I have been unable to get nREPL to work with SWT on Mac OS X.

To reproduce the problem, create a new SWT project with the following project.clj file:

```
(defproject swttest "0.1.0"
  :description "Foo"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.eclipse.swt/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64 "3.8"]]
  :jvm-opts ["-XstartOnFirstThread"]
  :repositories [["swt-repo" "https://swt-repo.googlecode.com/svn/repo/"]])
```

Then launch the REPL using "lein repl". Finally, run the following command:

```
user> (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.)
```

The following error occurs:

```
SWTException Invalid thread access  org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error (:-1)
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Instead of using nREPL, run it in a "dumb" REPL, by modifying the project.clj file to include a "dumbrepl" alias, like so:

```
(defproject swttest "0.1.0"
  :description "Foo"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.eclipse.swt/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64 "3.8"]]
  :jvm-opts ["-XstartOnFirstThread"]
  :aliases {"dumbrepl" ["trampoline" "run" "-m" "clojure.main/main"]}
  :repositories [["swt-repo" "https://swt-repo.googlecode.com/svn/repo/"]])
```

Then run:

```
> lein dumbrepl
```

Answer (score 1):

The lein command line starts several jvms. Only the first one runs with the -`XstartOnFirstThread` parameter. You can verify that by running `ps -aux|grep java` and looking at what lein repl does. That's why your "dumbrepl" works.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is basically what I figured out.